# Uniform Bound on fibres of a finite morphism between affine varieties.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, affine-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be two affine varieties (irreducible zero loci of polynomials over algebraically closed field). Let $\phi : X\rightarrow Y$ be a finite morphism (i.e. K[X] is finitely generated $\phi ^*(K[Y])-module$ ).  I want to show that there exists a natural number $n$ such that $|\phi^{-1}(p)|<n$ for every $p\in Y$.

Note that $K[X]$ denotes the affine coordinate ring of $X$.

I expect that this $n$ is the same as the number of finitely many generators but I am not able to deduce that. I know that fibers are finite (since finite maps preserve strict inclusions). Would anyone kindly provide a hint for this?

Comment: You can compare to what happens on the generic fiber.

Comment: A point $p \in Y$ gives a $K$-homomorphism $K[Y] \to \overline{K}$ and $\phi^* K[Y] \to \overline{K}$ which can be extended in at most $n=[Frac(K[X]):Frac(\phi^* K[Y])]$ ways to $K[X]$

Comment: @reuns how does it relate to the cardinality of fibers?